# CORS policy when working with environment

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 8 and I am trying to send a POST request to my API.

**This works:**

```js
this.http.post<number>('/api/login', data);
```

*proxyconfig.json*

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

**This gives an error:**

```js
this.http.post<number>(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/login', data);
```

*environment.ts*

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:80'
};
```

*Error:*
[image]

The reason why I would like to do it with environment is because I also have an environment.prod.ts file.

It cannot be a server-side issue, since the first way works. Why does the first one work but the second one gives an error?

Comment: you for `/api` before `/login` on `this.http.post<number>(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/login', data);`

Comment: use `apiBaseUrl: '/api'` instead of `apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:80'`

Comment: @bjdose oh wow, that works great. Thank you so much!!

Comment: you're very welcome!